# req.user not defined when calling from android application

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, express, passport.js

I am making an android app in partnership with a colleague, he is an Android developer and I know very little about android dev. I do the backend stuff, I made the login and auth using node.js, express, and passport.js.

I hosted the server locally and used postman to check the auth and registration processes, all were working fine. I am getting the status codes my friend wanted for his Front-end. In the authentication part using passport.js when success I am passing `req.user` which should return the user body, so that my friend on the Front-end can use the field `user.firstName` from user object to display a welcome message.

Through Postman, the user body is getting defined and I am getting a user object with all fields in the Postman window, but through the app it is giving an error.

> firstName is undefined property.

**Passport.js logic:**

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//load user model

const User = require('../models/UserSchema');

module.exports = function(passport){
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'roll'}, (roll, password, done) => {
      //find user
      User.findOne({roll: roll})
        .then(user =>{
        if(!user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Roll number not registered'});
        }

        //match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) =>{
          if(err) throw err;

          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          }else{
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Password incorrect'});
          }
        })


      })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

    })

  );

  /*passport.serializeUser( function(id, done)  {
        done(null, User.roll);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        User.findById(roll, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        });
    });*/


  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((_id, done) => {
    User.findById( _id, (err, user) => {
      if(err){
        done(null, false, {error:err});
      } else {
        done(null, user);
      }
    });
  });

}
```

**Login Route:**

```
//Login Handle

    router.post('/login', (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log('/user/login')
    passport.authenticate('local', {

        successRedirect: '/success',
        failureRedirect: '/failure',
        session: true,
        failureFlash: false

    })(req, res, next);
    //res.json(pass.user.name);
});
```

**/success route:**

```
    router.get('/success', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    let message = 'Login Succesful';
    //let user = req.user.firstName
    res.status(200).json({'message':message, 'user': req.user.firstName});
})
```

Comment: sorry one more small detail, I tried console.log the 'req' in the /success block and through postman, it is giving the object in the console like so:  

user: {
    balance: 20000,
    transactions: [],
    _id: 5e8cb6bbdb4dd34a30161f51,
    firstName: 'apple',
    lastName: 'singh',
    email: 'a@gmail.com',
    password: '$2a$10$Zp4VR5QE0qNkpz8fSdY8YuC7O0gQQqoKFNvFNrYcKvh18UwjQODCi',
    roll: 'BE/10193/16',
    date: 2020-04-07T17:22:03.681Z,
    __v: 0
  },



but through the front end app the req doesn't have a user object in the console.log.

Comment: Hey @Shamil you can edit your question to add the comment you just made

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are also using `body-parser` or `express.json()` to parse the incoming body request to JSON. If this is the case you should send the response back like this:

```
req.body.user.firstName
```

For POST requests: `req.body`

For GET parameters: `req.params`

For GET query strings: `req.query`